# Handling USR1 signals in python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, signals

I'm still new to signals in python and I want to know what is wrong with my program here.

I have
**prog1.py** :

```
import signal 
import os
import time


pid = os.getpid()

def receive(signum, stack):
    print("Received",signum)

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive)

print("PID is : ",pid)

while True:
    print("Waiting")
    time.sleep(3)
```

And **prog2.py** :

```
from prog1 import pid

n = 0

while True:
    n = n + 1
    print(n)
    if ( n % 10 == 0):
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

So what I want to do here is send a USR1 signal to prog1.py every time n is divisible by 10.

So first I run prog1.py so I can extract its pid and pass it to prog2.
Then I run prog2.py to get prog1's pid and send a USR1 signal to prog1 every time n is divisible by 10.
But what happens here is different : After running prog1 I get this output (which is excepted):

```
PID is :  15355
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
...
```

But when I run prog2, I get this output (which I didn't expect):

```
PID is :  15629
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
Waiting
...
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `getpidvalue()` called in prog2.py returns PID of itself, not prog1.py

Comment: I also tried with a variable but did not work aswell. I modified the code : shouldn't this work ?

Comment: It shouldn't, you still get PID of the process you in which you run `getpid()`

Comment: Hm I see, how should I do this then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fork prog1.py from prog2.py but run them
independently you have to save PID of prog1.py somewhere on the
filesystem and make prog2.py read it. Additionally, you'll quickly learn
that running `print()` in signal handler is a bad idea - signal handlers should be
very fast and run reentrant functions. At the end of the day, code
could look like this:

prog1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import signal
import os
import time


pid = os.getpid()

with open("/tmp/prog1.pid", "w") as pidfile:
    pidfile.write(f"{pid}\n")

GOT = 0


def receive(signum, stack):
    global GOT
    GOT = 1


signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive)

print("PID is : ", pid)

while True:
    if GOT == 1:
        print("Received signal.SIGUSR1")
        GOT = 0

    print("Waiting")
    time.sleep(3)
```

prog2.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import signal

with open("/tmp/prog1.pid", "r") as pidfile:
    prog1_pid = int(pidfile.readline())

N = 0

while True:
    N = N + 1
    if N % 10 == 0:
        os.kill(prog1_pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Comment: Quick question: I was trying to implement another idea : This command can get me the last pid used by prog1 : `pgrep -f prog1 | tail -n 1` , it was printing the right pid when running it in the terminal , but when implementing this in prog2 , I get again the pid of prog2 `output = subprocess.check_output("pgrep -f prog1 | tail -n 1", shell=True)
print(output)` So apparently, prog2 prints the PID of itself although I mentioned prog1 in the command . Why ?